# How to push data to Segment.io from GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I read that it is possible to send GTM data to Segment. But did not find any resource to do that.

If someone has worked on this can point me to the same?

Thanks in advance,
Amit

Comment: I can't really answer the question, but I am curious: wouldn't using a tag manager to feed data to Segment basically defeat the purpose of Segment ? (case in point, their default integration works the other way round - normally you would send Segment data to GTM).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Even I thought so, but since it was mentioned on the Segment.com documentation that GTM-to-Segment integration is possible, I wanted to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use Segment template in community gallery.

https://tagmanager.google.com/gallery/#/owners/slide-rule-tech/templates/gtm-segment-template

It offers track, identify, page calls to your segment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know how to implement Segment code through Google Tag Manager?

It's simply install the Segment JS library within it:

[Segment JS Library Document](https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/libraries/website/javascript/)

How easy is that will depend on how you familiar with Google Tag Manger

I assume you already have the source call `JavaScript` in Segment

[image]

Then the first step is create a `Tag` in GoogleTagManager

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Then you will have to install the code for `identify(), track()` according to the tracking plan for the website.